# My login ajax form isn't working on codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have written login form in CodeIgniter. it submits the information to the database when I write wrong data it gives me errors and validation errors which I want. But when I write right username and pass and press `LOG IN` it just does nothing, but when I refresh the page it shows that I am logged in. I want it to redirect the main page immediately after I press login. I think that the problem is in ajax or controller, but I don't know exactly. Because when I press log in with the correct username and pass it shows nothing in the console.

Here is my view:

```
<div id="loginmsg"></div>

                    <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'rex-forms', 'name' => 'loginform', 'id' => 'loginform'); ?>
                  <?= form_open_multipart('user/login', $attributes); ?>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input name="usernameforlog" id="usernameforlog" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя пользователя">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">

                          <input name="passwordforlog" id="passwordforlog" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль">
                      </div>                   
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="submitforlog" class="rex-bottom-medium rex-btn-icon btnsubmitforlog">
                        <span class="rex-btn-text">войти</span>
                        <span class="rex-btn-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></span>
                    </button>    
                  </div>
                    </form>
```

here is my controller (I commented redirect line because it doesn't work):

```
public function login(){
            $data['title'] = 'Sign In';

        $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        $validate_data = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'usernameforlog',
                'label' => 'username',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_dash'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'passwordforlog',
                'label' => 'password',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|md5'
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($validate_data);
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>'); 


            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                // fails
                $validator['success'] = false;
                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                    $validator['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
                }
            }else {

                // Get username
                $username = $this->input->post('usernameforlog');
                // Get and encrypt the password
                $password = $this->input->post('passwordforlog');
                // Login user
                $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);
                if($user_id){
                    // Create session

                    $user_data = array(
                        'instructor_id' => $instructor_id,
                        'id' => $id,
                        'instructors_slug' => $username,
                        'name' => $name,
                        'logged_in' => true
                        );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                    $validator['success'] = true;
                    $validator['messages'] = array();
                    //redirect('');
                } else {

                    $validator['success'] = false;
                    $validator['messages'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Неверный логин или пароль</div>';
                }       
            }

            echo json_encode($validator);
        }
```

and here is my model:

```
public function login($username, $password) {
            //validate
            $this->db->where('instructors_slug', $username);
            $this->db->where('password', $password);
            $result = $this->db->get('instructors');

            if($result->num_rows() == 1){
                return $result->row(0)->id;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and here is ajax file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);              
                if(response.success) {
                    //i want here to redirect main page

                }
                else {
                    $("#loginmsg").html(response.messages);

                    $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                        var element = $("#"+index);

                        $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .removeClass('has-success')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger').remove();

                        $(element).after(value);

                    });
                }
            } // /success
        });  // /ajax

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have done everything. It shows errors in the console but not inside the form.

Comment: what you getting in console.log(response);

Comment: You have to clear the errors in the console.

Comment: I think it might have to do with that `redirect()`. In CI, `redirect()` is a shortcut for a PHP `header()` redirect. So you're redirecting before the AJAX request finishes. If you're trying to do the redirect with javascript it will never get there.

Comment: @VK321 i get this https://yadi.sk/i/Wov19YWP3KzgqW

Comment: @JayBlanchard how?

Comment: @JamesMeisler it did not work

Comment: Press the F12 key.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it did nothing

Comment: its working now?

Comment: @VK321 not yet :(

Comment: Anybody here?  :(

Comment: Pressing F12 did nothing?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @JayBlanchard google chrome

Comment: Pressing the F12 key should open Chrome's developer tools. If it doesn't you may need to re-install Chrome. Without being able to get information from the console or watch the requests you will have a hard time troubleshooting what the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149122/discussion-between-a-aliyev-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I am unable to chat from my current location. Is there a link to you your site where I can view the problem?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no :( can you enter through team viewer?

Comment: No, I cannot do that.

Comment: İ do not know other variants

Comment: ok let me help you with this. I need to test it. ok

Comment: İ have edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your array when you setting session.

Not defined variables $instructor_id, $id etc

```
  $user_data = array(
                    'instructor_id' => $instructor_id,
                    'id' => $id,
                    'instructors_slug' => $username,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'logged_in' => true
                    );
```

Comment: @A.Aliyev - are you loading session library too?

Comment: open config.php and $config['log_threshold'] = 1; and tell me what you getting in logs

Comment: Yes. It logs in. but it logs  in after refreshing page. But i want it reload page automatically

Comment: I am not talking about login as signin i am talking about error logs

Comment: I made  $config['log_threshold']  = 1. what should i do next?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149178/discussion-between-vk321-and-a-aliyev).

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code in the controller:

```
                    if($user_id){
                    // Create session

                     $user_data = array(
                        'instructor_id' => $instructor_id,
                        'id' => $id,
                        'instructors_slug' => $username,
                        'name' => $name,
                        'logged_in' => true
                        );

                     $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                     $validator['success'] = true;
                     $validator['messages'] = array();//In case no data needs to be passed
                     //  redirect('');//Comment this part as it will redirect and don't pass the data to the AJAX call    
                    }else{
                      //Your else part
                    }
                 //here just json encode and return .
```

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?Have you done console.log(response);return false; and seen what is the response you are getting ?

Comment: I don't get an error. I get nothing :D When I enter it does not redirect to the main page, I should refresh it. And when I leave login form empty and press submit it should show errors under the input fields but it doesn't, it shows errors in console like this https://yadi.sk/i/-fpVtCi23L2Sne

Comment: in the ajax call's sucess function put the following code :if(response.success) {
       alert("TEST ABC 123");
return false;
                }

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: that's probably the problem with your Ajax call/Controller code..Hard to figure it out..You have to debug it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149106/discussion-between-a-aliyev-and-ketan-solanki).